# What does it mean "the content provider can be instantiated by the system"?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, instantiation

A few times in Android's components I've encountered a sentence

> ... can be instantiated by the system

in particular [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#enabled)

> Whether or not the content provider can be instantiated by the system — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not

So what does it mean with regard to [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)? (BTW `Content Provider` component is new to me - I know other Android components)

1. When it can happen `Content Provider` is instantiated by system?
2. Why it can happen?
3. What benefit my app gets from this by-system instantiation?

Comment: It means you don't create instances of app components with `new`. The system handles it

Comment: Do you ever instances CP with new? I don't think so...

Comment: Nope. Just like `Activities` and `Service`s, you can't use `new` to instantiate a `ContentProvider`, and have it work correctly.

Comment: IMO a benefit of system-instantiated is: the CP could be located in other app, and marked as public (`android:exported="true"`) so if you want to use `new` you would have to include classes of this CP in your project which could be hard or not possible. while "system" doing this for you add flexibility and easiness

Comment: Check some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/a/8272493/5766983
So you can control (enable/disable) free vs payed features of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I could not answer the 3 questions separately, as they intersect somehow,
so here is a little answer, i hope it's correct, and i hope you find it useful:

**as of Why/when**

You should not use `new` you have to use `getContentResolver()` which creates instance and then you can call proper method: `query()`, `update()`, ...

```
getContentResolver().update(...);
```

**As of benefits**

If the CP is located in other app, and marked as public

```
android:exported="true"
```

then you can use it from your app, but how ?
*and by using i mean query/delete/update...*

If you want to use `new` you would have to include classes/jar/resources... of this CP in your project which could be hard or not possible. while "system" doing this for you **getContentResolver()** provides (for publisher and consumer):

1. flexibility
2. easiness
3. more secure

Answer (score 0):

All the android application components Activity, Service, ContentProvider and BroadcastReceiver(except dynamic) are instantiated by the system when ever a request comes.

Ex:

Activity is instantiated by the system when ever someone calls `startActivity()` with an `Intent`

Similarly, `ContentProvider` is also instantiated by the system when somebody request to access the data provided by the ContentProvider using [ContentResolver.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) or [ContentResolver.insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#insert(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues)) by passing the respective URI.