# Conditionally add <activity> tag on AndroidManifest.xml using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-manifest

I have an application that only have Services, Receivers and Activities that are not directly accessed by the use (there is no launcher activity).

But now I have to add an activity to be used as launcher activity **BUT** this launcher activity must be present only when the app has some specific variables set during the BUILD.

So basically, when calling the gradle build I set a variable `HAS_LAUNCHER=1` and in my **build.gradle** I have something like:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    def hasLauncher = System.getenv("HAS_LAUNCHER")
    if (hasLauncher != null && hasLauncher == "1") {
        // Something here to include the activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml
    }
}
```

And in my AndroidManifest I have to add the `<activity>` tag when that `if` condition is true:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LauncherActivity"
    android:label="Launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

---

How can I accomplish that without using a new dimension of productFlavors? *(the app already has a dimension with 3 flavors and 2 buildTypes, so I don't want to make even more outputs)*

Comment: one thing you can use is the `enabled` attribute of the activity tag

Comment: "this launcher activity must be present" -- what does "present" mean in this context? Do you mean that the activity must only be enabled in certain builds? BTW, you seem to be missing something before your `<hr>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah, the launcher activity should be in the apk only in certain builds, while other builds should only have the services, receivers and other activities. (and yeah, I pressed the ASK button by accident, but now I edited the question)

Comment: This will require splitting the activity and its manifest entry out into a separate sourceset. Whether that sourceset is one of your existing ones or not, I cannot say. It's not out of the question that you could somehow modify the build tools to handle some sort of non-sourceset exclusion rules, but that would seem to be *much* more complex than having an additional flavor dimension, should one be required.

Comment: @njzk2 I tried using something like `android:enabled` or `tools:node="remove"` but I would need to have a way of modifying the value of the attributes from the build.gradle file. I tried using manifestPlaceholders but this don't seem to work in these attributes.

Answer (score 8):

may be too late, but after many days searching for a solution I have done in this way :

gradle defaultConfig

```
defaultConfig {
    resValue "bool", "showActivity", "true"
...
```

In the builTypes

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        resValue "bool", "showActivity", "false"
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

In manifest

```
    <activity
     android:name="xxx.xx.xxx"
        android:enabled="@bool/showActivity"
        android:label="@string/myActivity"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences">
    ...
```

This way you can control activity visibility from gradle. Note that you can also use **in code** , just create a bool resource **showActivity** , it will be replaced by gradle value and you'll be able to read it

```
context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.showActivity)
```