# Something like #if #endif for AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, c++, oculusquest

I develop 3D engine (c++ in visual studio) for windows/android/android oculus.
On Android, I use `AndroidManifest.xml`, where I need

```
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.vr.application.mode" android:value="vr_only">
```

VR_ONLY for oculus, and

```
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.vr.application.mode" android:value="vr_dual"/>
```

with VR_DUAL for mobile phones. Is there any way how to write any #if #def like in c++? Because now I have to rewrite this file every time I switch device.

Comment: No there isn't, and also this is not a C++ question so I'm removing the C++ tag.

Comment: (actually I can't remove the tag until someone else reviews the pending edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if this works at all it's through gradle during the build process. check this links out:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283428/conditionally-add-activity-tag-on-androidmanifest-xml-using-gradle) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130918/conditionally-include-meta-data-in-android-manifest-file)